# sending mails from users own email id

Tags: node.js, smtp, smtp-auth, mass-emails

I am working on a project that allows users to send e-mails from their own email ids using my app, currently, I am using Gmail API's with nodemailer, it still requires users to authenticate and provide permissions and is limited to Gmail users, I was looking how apps like Mailchimp etc send mail without oAuth from users behalf just by OTP verification.

Comment: I am not sure if the mass emailing is allowed from personal Email ID. There is a restriction on the number of emails that can be sent from your personal Gmail ID. It is set to 500 if I am not wrong.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.